# Повариха или повар?

Tags: выбор-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли специалист и/или профессия повариха? Или, все–таки, правильно повар?

Answer (score 3):

Профессия ПОВАР, а повариха - разговорное, бытовое использование.